# Automatically Printing Page, then directing to next page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am updating an old application, and have been asked to change the old Print routine (which just invoked the print command via javascript, and printed out the html), to one that prints out a pdf (the theory being that we then have more control of the pdf / how it looks etc across all printers.)

Using the Rotativa library, I can generate my pdf's, either on the fly or to a file.

After doing some reading, it appears impossible to stream a pdf from memory, and it has to be created as a file first, sent to the browser, and then deleted.)

the last line of my controller is;

```
return File(@"D:\Development\Source\Workspaces\ConsumerCreditLicenseSystem\Code\ConsumerCreditSystem\CCLSystem\_Idd\1.pdf", "application/pdf");
```

What I am strugglign with is getting that page to invoke the Print Dialog. If I send it to a new view with javascript to do this, then I am back to square one as the page is html not my pdf. Is there any way I can mark that my pdf is for printing, or combine it with some html so I can have the old faithful of

```
window.print();
```

in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PDF is not a webpage; it's a binary. When you send the PDF as a response to the user, you have no control over what happens on their end. If their browser is capable of viewing a PDF in place, it will display it; otherwise, it will prompt the user to download it. Either way, it will be up to the user whether they want to print it or not, and it will also be up to them to go back or whatever. You cannot redirect the user automatically at this point.

A slightly better option would be to redirect the user to another page, with a link to a view that will send the PDF down to them. Then, you can do things like force the PDF to download (so it's not rendered inside the same tab/window, effectively taking the user away from your site), or force the link to open in a new tab or window. However, you still will not be able to prompt the user to print.

Comment: I suppose 'force' was an incorrect phrase. they have alreaady clicked on a link that says "Print", so what I need to do is convert the html to a pdf (which I have done), and then get that printed. If thats not possible then I'll have to stick with the original method, and see if I can tidy up the print css a little.

Comment: Yeah, no, prompting the user to print is out at that point. All you can do is send the PDF and let them decide what they want to do with it. If you need to pop the print dialog, then you need to stick with an HTML based view.